# is possible merge material?

Tags: merge, three.js, texture-atlas

I am a newbie. I'm using three to create a Rubik's Cube game, and the problem is that there are too many drawcalls. A 5x5 Rubik's Cube game needs at least 275 drawcalls. which is particularly obvious on phones with poor performance. Is there any way to optimize it?
For example, a cube at the corner of a Rubik's Cube needs 3 faces with colors(see picture flow). This cube needs at last 4 drawcalls. Is there any way to make it only need one drawcall?
Is it possible to merge materials into one so that it only requires one drawcall.
I am not allowed to embed image.
[this is image url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnHRP.jpg)

Comment: Should only require 110 draw calls for 5x5 rubik's cube. Use a texture atlas or vertex colors to give the cubes on the edges a different color on each face.

Comment: @gman Thanks for your comment.I will try your solution.